# VB.net Form Assign Tab Index with Tab Control in between

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, tabcontrol, tabindex

I have, First Field on Main Form then Tab Control with Some Fields and then Some Buttons again on Main Form

I have Set Tab Index , First Field on Main Form = 1, Field in Tab Control = 2, Button on Main Form = 3

But my tab goes from First Field to Button , it does not go to Tab Control Field

Is there anyway it should follow first field and then field in tab control and then to buttons

Thanks
Pramod

Comment: You are doing it wrong.  The TabControl must have TabIndex = 2.  The controls inside each tab page start numbering over again.

Answer (score 1):

- Open your form in the design mode.
- Click on "View" from the top menu and then click "Tab Order".
- You will see that the controls on the form takes a numbers like this:

[image: Tab Order]

- Now click the controls one by one as order as you need.